# ulimit: what is the maximum core file size value

Tags: docker, ulimit

I want to set unlimited core file size with ulimit inside docker. I can't do this by

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

because parameters for docker are set by framework, that doesn't accept `unlimited` parameter. So I need to set it by passing direct value. I found that 9223372036854775807 is the max value, but when I set it, I get:

```
ulimit: 9223372036854775807: limit out of range
```

How can I find max value which I can pass to `ulimit -c` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the limits on the container on Docker run with the `--ulimit` flag.

```
docker run --ulimit core=<size> ...
```

Note that "unlimited" is not a supported value since it is not actually a real value, but -1 is equivalent to it:

```
$ docker run -it --ulimit core=-1 ubuntu:18.04 sh -c 'ulimit -a | grep core'
coredump(blocks)     unlimited
```

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the `RLIMIT_CORE` limit (see `setrlimit(2)` man page), is expressed in bytes. While for the `ulimit` of `bash` and most other shells, it's expressed in kibibytes.

The max value for `RLIMIT_CORE` in bytes that you can pass to `setrlimit()` on Linux will be the largest unsigned 64 bit integer (18446744073709551615), bearing in mind that it is actually the special value for `RLIM_INFINITY`, the max that you can pass to bash's `ulimit` will be that divided by 1024, 18014398509481983, but then, that will not set the limit to `RLIMIT_INFINITY` as `18014398509481983 * 1024` is 18446744073709550592 which is 1023 short of `RLIM_INFINITY`.